# Get image file name from HTML img tag by using RegEx in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have huge HTML code.

I wanna replace all img tags with their base image files in Notepad++.

Available code;

```
<td>
    <img class='hello' src='http://www.example.com/images/items/myitem.png' alt='My Item'/>
</td>
```

Replaced Code;

```
<td>
    myitem
</td>
```

So by Using Notepad++  Replace Function (CTRL+H) can you please give an example RegEx script to replace them all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find what:

```
<img\b[^<>]*?src=['"].*?\/([^.\/<>]*)\.[^.\/<>]*['"][^><]*?\/>
```

Replace With:

```
$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rA1lZ1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the matches from following pattern:

```
<img.* src=(['"])\S*\/([^.]+)\.(?:png|gif|jpg)\1[^>]*>
```

with the second matched group in the pattern. You can add multiple file extensions if you want in the pattern.